# jquery ajax generating query string if undefined do not pass

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, query-string

Hi I am using jquery and ajax to post and get data from a CMS API. I am generating a query string to fetch the data as so:

```
region = typeof region !== 'undefined' ? 'region='+region : '';
centre = typeof centre !== 'undefined' ? 'centre='+centre : '';

data = region+centre; // generate query string
```

Now I thought the above would not pass anything if is undefined but if I console log `data` when I click on a button that triggers the centre variable it passes `region="undefined"centre="Centre Market"`. However I want it to just pass `centre="Centre Market"` which would be the href of the button clicked.

This is my click function:

```
$('ul.dropdown li a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    console.info('Selected Centre: "' + $(this).attr('href') + '"');
    var centre = $(this).attr('href');
    getData.update('/overview', 'undefined' centre);
});
```

As you can see this passes the `href` attribute to the getData.update function this function is below...

```
var getData = {

    update: function (url, region, centre) {

    region = typeof region !== 'undefined' ? 'region='+region : ''; 
    centre = typeof centre !== 'undefined' ? 'centre='+centre : '';
    // i dont want to pass region if it is undefined
    data = region+centre; // generate query string

    console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data, // data passed here
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (json) {
              //success stuff....
           }
        });
    }
}
```

as you can see I am passing the data into the ajax function as so:

```
data = region+centre; // generate query string
```

so if region is undefined or empty or not passed I don't want this to be apart of the query string i.e. don't include `region=`. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check for null instead, and add a check for string (you could just check for typeof string):

```
$('ul.dropdown li a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    console.info('Selected Centre: "' + $(this).attr('href') + '"');
    var centre = $(this).attr('href');
    getData.update('/overview', null, centre);
});
```

As you can see this passes the href attribute to the getData.update function this function is below...

```
var getData = {

update: function (url, region, centre) {

region = (region != null && typeof region == 'string') ? 'region='+region : ''; 
centre = typeof centre !== 'undefined' ? 'centre='+centre : '';
// i dont want to pass region if it is undefined
data = region+centre; // generate query string

console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data, // data passed here
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (json) {
          //success stuff....
       }
    });
}
```

}